# How do you reset all migrations for an app in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django

I am currently using postgres and I dropped a table in my events app. Now I'm getting all sorts of bugs when I try to run `makemigrations` like:

```
 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "events_event" does not exist
```

How do you reset all migrations and models for an app in Django 1.7? Also is there an easy way to reset individual models within an app? In my case I would just like to drop the Event table then recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all records from south_migrationhistory table in your database, and delete all migration files from /migrations... (or delete only problem migration files because if you delete all migration files you shoul make initial migration again)

Comment: Django 1.7+ includes migration capabilities. I don't believe that I am using South. I make migrations like this: python manage.py makemigrations events ... python manage.py migrate

Comment: I have no experience with Django 1.7 yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to start from initial migration:

In your app, there is a folder named `migrations`. Just delete all the files in that folder except the `__init__.py` file.That will reset migrations history for you.

Then when you run the `makemigrations` command, it will start from initial migration!

2) If you want to delete and/or add specific models then maybe you will need to either manually edit the migration files depending on your need.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#migration-files Or you can delete specific migration files according to your requirement